# Order effects test for randomized stimuli

Tags: r, repeated-measures

I'm trying to address a reviewer's comment about the 'development of expectations' for a within-subjects variable.

In brief, one of the variables was varied within-subjects and the order of presentation was randomised. The reviewer wants me to check whether participants become less sensitive to the manipulation with each 'scenario' that they read.

I have details of the randomisation order for each participant, but I'm unsure how to test whether sensitivity decreases.

My data structure looks a little like this:

```
structure(list(J_CompMean = c(7, 7, 4.66666666666667, 3, 2.66666666666667, 
4, 3.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 7, 1.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 
5, 2.66666666666667, 4, 4.33333333333333, 7, 6.66666666666667, 
7, 6.33333333333333, 5, 5.33333333333333, 5, 5, 4.66666666666667, 
5.33333333333333, 6.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
7, 6, 4.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 
4, 4, 4, 3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 7, 2.33333333333333, 
3, 2, 3, 4, 1.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 
4, 4, 1.66666666666667, 6, 2, 4.66666666666667, 3, 3.33333333333333, 
2.33333333333333, 2, 4.66666666666667, 3, 1, 5, 1, 5.33333333333333, 
2.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 3, 1.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 
3.33333333333333, 2, 4, 3, 3.33333333333333, 4, 1.33333333333333, 
4, 2, 4, 3.33333333333333, 2, 1, 2.66666666666667, 2, 1, 2.66666666666667, 
2, 2.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 3, 3, 1.33333333333333, 
6, 1.66666666666667, 3, 4, 3.33333333333333, 6, 5, 3.66666666666667, 
2.66666666666667), P_CompMean = c(7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5.33333333333333, 
5.66666666666667, 6, 7, 4.33333333333333, 5.66666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 
5.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 7, 7, 7, 
6, 5.33333333333333, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 
5.33333333333333, 6.66666666666667, 6, 7, 6.66666666666667, 7, 
7, 6.66666666666667, 7, 6.66666666666667, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4.33333333333333, 
6, 7, 3.33333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 5, 4, 3.33333333333333, 
2, 3.33333333333333, 4, 2.66666666666667, 6, 6.33333333333333, 
7, 6, 6.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 5, 
4, 5.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 7, 6, 1.33333333333333, 
4, 1, 4.66666666666667, 2, 2.66666666666667, 3, 4.33333333333333, 
1.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 6, 5.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
1, 3.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 4, 4, 2.66666666666667, 
4, 6, 3, 4.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 
2.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 
5, 4, 5, 4.33333333333333, 4, 5.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 
4.33333333333333, 4, 4), R_CompMean = c(7, 7, 5.33333333333333, 
5.66666666666667, 7, 4.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 
7, 3, 6, 6.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 6, 3, 6, 6.33333333333333, 
3, 2.66666666666667, 5, 7, 6, 7, 3, 6.33333333333333, 6, 6.66666666666667, 
5.33333333333333, 7, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.33333333333333, 
5, 5.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
3, 3, 6, 4, 3, 3, 3.66666666666667, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3.66666666666667, 
6, 3, 6.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 3, 
3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 6.66666666666667, 
3, 3, 3, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 
3, 4, 5.66666666666667, 3, 3.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 
4.33333333333333, 3, 3.33333333333333, 4, 1.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
3, 5, 5, 5, 2.66666666666667, 3, 5, 3.66666666666667, 3, 4, 3.33333333333333, 
4, 4.66666666666667, 4, 5.33333333333333, 6.66666666666667, 4, 
5.66666666666667, 3, 6, 2.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
3), S_CompMean = c(7, 6.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 
7, 5, 3, 6.33333333333333, 7, 1.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 
6.33333333333333, 5, 3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 7, 7, 
6, 2.33333333333333, 5, 5, 5, 5.33333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 
7, 6, 5.66666666666667, 7, 7, 7, 6.33333333333333, 7, 4.33333333333333, 
3, 5, 4, 3.66666666666667, 5, 2.66666666666667, 6, 2.66666666666667, 
3, 4.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 
2, 3.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 6, 4.33333333333333, 5.66666666666667, 
3.66666666666667, 2, 3.33333333333333, 1.66666666666667, 3, 3.66666666666667, 
2.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 2, 3.66666666666667, 1, 3, 
2, 3, 3.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
1.66666666666667, 4, 2, 5, 4, 1.33333333333333, 4, 2.33333333333333, 
4, 2.33333333333333, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2.66666666666667, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
3.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 
3, 2.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 5, 3.66666666666667, 
3.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333), First = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Journalist", "Police", "Reviewer", 
"Spokesperson"), class = "factor"), Second = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Journalist", "Police", "Reviewer", 
"Spokesperson"), class = "factor"), Third = structure(c(1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Journalist", "Police", "Reviewer", "Spokesperson"
), class = "factor"), Fourth = structure(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L
), .Label = c("Journalist", "Police", "Reviewer", "Spokesperson"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -101L), class = "data.frame")
```

There are a lot of other measurements included but I wanted to simplify things for this example.

The four final columns indicate which scenario they saw first, second, third, and fourth.

I guess I need to convert the data frame to long format as well but I'm not sure how to do this with the order variables. Following that, I have no idea how I can test for the development of expectations/decrease in sensitivity.

Should I treat as a within-subjects variable and test for decreases in time?